# Adjusting out of working hour Date-time to Next working day 8AM in T-SQL (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a bit of problem. For the most part, I know what to do, just checking if there is a smarter way to do it. There are tickets created in our system (they have timestamps obviously). The working hours are 9 AM to 8 PM (Weekday- i.e., Mon-Fri). We check the time difference between Ticket Created time and Ticket Worked time by using the datediff function.

Problem occurs when tickets are generated outside the working hours. We are thinking of adjusting the tickets created outside the working hours to the next working day 8AM, and then calculating the time taken to action those items.

```
CASE
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,Created_Time) IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday') 
            AND DATEPART(HOUR,Action_Time) BETWEEN @Calling_Start_Time AND @Calling_End_Time 
                THEN 'In Week and Within Shift- Same time'
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,Created_Time) IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday') 
            AND DATEPART(HOUR,Action_Time) NOT BETWEEN @Calling_Start_Time AND @Calling_End_Time 
                THEN 'In Week and OUTSIDE Shift- Next day 8 AM'
            WHEN (DATENAME(dw,Created_Time) = 'Friday' 
            AND DATEPART(HOUR,Action_Time) NOT BETWEEN @Calling_Start_Time AND @Calling_End_Time )
            OR DATENAME(dw,Created_Time) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
                THEN 'Friday OUTSIDE Shift- Next Monday 8 AM'
            WHEN DATENAME(dw,Created_Time) = 'Friday' 
            AND DATEPART(HOUR,Action_Time) NOT BETWEEN @Calling_Start_Time AND @Calling_End_Time 
                THEN 'Friday OUTSIDE Shift- Next Monday 8 AM'
            ELSE 'Weekend'

END for_Adjusted
```

I was just in the middle of writing this, when I thought there has to be a better way to do this. Hence, checking with all you folks. Please help.

EDIT:

Here is the sample data and what I want:

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
IC_Created_Local_UA|    IC_Created_Weekday_Name    |    IC_Created_Adjusted   |     Logic
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
10/28/2018 12:31   |    Sunday             |    10/29/2018 09:00      | Weekends should adjust to Monday 9:00AM
10/29/2018 04:44   |    Monday             |    10/29/2018 09:00      | Case: Monday Before Shift
10/29/2018 12:44   |    Monday             |    10/29/2018 12:44      | Case: Monday IN Shift (Weekday IN Shift remains same time)
10/29/2018 21:30   |    Monday             |    10/30/2018 09:00      | Case Monday After Shift (Mon- thur after shift adjusts to Next day 9:00 AM)
11/02/18 21:00     |    Friday             |    11/05/2018 09:00      | case Friday after shift adjusts to next Monday 9: am
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you want to do.

Comment: I did put the sample now, please recheck , thanks a lot

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs of the [TSQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you considered creating a table of `NonworkingHours` containing `DayOfWeek`, `DaysOffset`, `StartTime` and `EndTime`? You could use it to identify which day/time values need to be adjusted, how many days to add (`DaysOffset` used for weekends.) and the appropriate start time for the corrected day, i.e. the `EndTime` for the day's nonworking time. (If it makes more sense to you, you can flip it all to define `WorkShifts` instead of nonworking times.) You could further extend this to reference a `Calendar` table that includes holidays.